# How to convert List[String] to List[Object] in Scala

Tags: scala, play-json

I need to change from one `List[String]` to `List[MyObject]` in scala.

For example,JSON input is like below

```json
employee: {
  name: "test",
  employeeBranch: ["CSE", "IT", "ECE"]
}
```

Output should be like this,

```json
Employee: {
  Name: "test",
  EmployeeBranch:[{"branch": "CSE"}, {"branch": "IT"}, {"branch": "ECE"}]
}
```

Input case class:

```scala
Class Office(
name: Option[String],
employeeBranch: Option[List[String]])
```

Output case class:

```scala
Class Output(
Name: Option[String],
EmployeeBranch: Option[List[Branch]])

case class Branch(
branch: Option[String])
```

This is the requirement.

Comment: Which json lib are you using? What have you already tried? What are the encountered errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I will get Input JSON like employee: {
  name: "test",
  employeeBranch: ["CSE", "IT", "ECE"]
} from UI. And I need to process it and I need to make output json like below by using scala                                  Employee: {
  Name: "test",
  EmployeeBranch:[{"branch": "CSE"}, {"branch": "IT"}, {"branch": "ECE"}]
}

Comment: I will be using play.api.json

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to answer without knowing details of the particular JSON library, but an `Object` is probably represented as a `Map`. So to convert a `List[String]` to a `List[Map[String, String]]` you can do this:

```
val list = List("CSE", "IT", "ECE")
val map = list.map(x => Map("branch" -> x))
```

This gives

```
List(Map(branch -> CSE), Map(branch -> IT), Map(branch -> ECE))
```

which should convert to the JSON you want.

Comment: Input case class:

Class Office( name: Option[String], employeeBranch: Option[List[String]])

Output case class: Class Output( Name: Option[String], EmployeeBranch: Option[List[Branch]])

case class Branch( branch: Option[String])

This is the requirement.

Comment: I edited in questions also for case class